# What's Ramda equivalent to underscore.js 'compact'?

Tags: ramda.js

Does Ramda have a function to remove false values from a list?

I know we can simply do `var compact = R.filter(R.identity);` but am I missing the ready-made function?

Comment: would be nice to have an alias, anyway.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There's no direct equivalent, but `R.filter(R.identity)` and `R.filter(Boolean)` both work.

`R.reject(R.isNil)` is useful for filtering out null/undefined.

Answer (score 8):

You can use Ramda Adjunct's [compact](https://char0n.github.io/ramda-adjunct/2.5.0/RA.html#.compact) which works like the Underscore / Lodash equivalents.

```
RA.compact([0, 1, false, 2, '', 3]); //=> [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Sadly this doesn't appear to be available as of 10/20/19

Comment: @MobileVet https://char0n.github.io/ramda-adjunct/2.21.0/RA.html#.compact

Comment: Whoops... Didn't see the 'Adjunct' call out.  My bad, thanks!